# Why did Ahsoka's lightsaber grip change?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

When Ahsoka first appeared, she consistently used one lightsaber in a reverse grip, occasionally switching to a normal/frontward grip when the situation required
[image: Ahsoka fighting Ventress]
(It's hard to see, but she is using a backwards grip here. I couldn't find a better picture)

When she got her shoto, she began using both lightsabers in a reverse grip.
[image: Ahsoka fighting Visla]

Later, when she had her white lighsabers, she used her previous style of mostly using a reverse grip and occasionally switching to a front grip on one or both lightsabers when the situation required it. She does seem to favor a front grip a little bit more during this period, which makes sense since, as far as I can tell, a front grip is superior in lightsaber v. lightsaber combat since it allows more powerful strokes, but a reverse grip can be more effective for blaster bolt deflection because it favors more movement (speculation), and she would mostly be avoiding using her lightsabers to stay hidden and only using them to fight other lightsaber users until she becomes an open rebel.

[image: Ahsoka fighting inquisitors]
(shows forward and reverse grips)

During the Siege of Mandalore, once she got her lightsabers back (but blue, for some reason), she began mainly using a forwards grip on her main lightsaber and a backwards grip on her shoto. This change doesn't really make sense, because she wouldn't have had a chance to practice with her lightsabers since leaving the Jedi order, and she is planning to fight someone very dangerous, which is not the time you would want to be experimenting with a new technique. She even does this when being shot at by a large group, when her previous style of two reverse grip lightsabers would seem to be superior. **Why did she do this, or is it just my perception that she normally used reverse grips?**

[image: Ahsoka fighting position]
[image]
(two pictures of Ahsoka about to be shot at)

Comment: It's probably no more than "rule of cool" since a sideways stance like in the last picture wouldn't look as good with both lightsabers in forward grip.  But I will note that stance is very much how one might stand if fighting with a sword and shield.

Comment: Did she get her Sabers back? Or did Anakin give her new ones? I don't remember... But if he gave her new ones then that would be why. I noticed this too tho! And lemme just comment how freaking BA the final season was... IT WAS FANTASTIC!

Comment: @DavidW That's an interesting point about the sword and shield. I hadn't thought about it that way. I honestly think her previous way of both in a reverse grip is cooler though

Comment: @dustbuster Anakin gave her back her old ones. He said he maintained them and somehow changed the color to blue.

Comment: Wookiepedia talks about it. Just says “sometimes she used reverse grips” 

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka%27s_lightsabers

Comment: Its her choice, let her be. Dont question freaking everything!!!

Answer (score 1):

This pertains to the fact that she very rarely fought other people with her green lightsabers. She would mainly use Jar’Kai (fighting with 2 lightsabers) defensively, returning blaster bolts to the clankers. When she fought other people, she would switch to forward grip because it is much easier to slice and stab in that grip. If she continued to use reverse grip, her fighting style contained a lot of sweeping slices. When she was fighting Maul, the thing was filmed with motion capture, thus the actor used the blades in forward grip.

Comment: But in the first photo she is fighting someone with her green lightsabers and she is using a reverse grip.  So your second assertion is dubious without some additional evidence.

Answer (score -1):

If you see the arc with obi-wan disguised, there's a scene when it seems she uses forward grip and reverse grip to protect more of herself, so that could be part of it

Comment: Which arc, which episode, which scene? Can you please be a lot more specific.

Comment: I think the arc is either the Box Tornement, where obi-wan is the bounty hunter, or the duchess satine + Death Watch arc, with kenobi is a mando.